# Problemas del menu sandwich respecto al pointer

Tags: html, css

espero que me ayuden este problema, lo que pasa es que el menu sandwich que le llamen, se vizualiza el rellenado de blanco de todo la caja, al momento que se carga la pagina y al indicar con el cursor del mouse para seleccionar se desaparece el rellenado. Aqui el codigo:

```css
.sidebarBtn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 101;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 16px;
  /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
  width: 27px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  height: 26px;
  /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
  top: 25px;
  outline: 10px solid transparent;
}

.sidebarBtn span {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -1px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0 0.3s;
  transition: background 0 0.3s;
}

.sidebarBtn span:before,
.sidebarBtn span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  -moz-transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  -o-transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
}

.sidebarBtn span:before {
  top: -8px;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: top, -moz-transform;
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.sidebarBtn span:after {
  bottom: -8px;
  -webkit-transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: bottom, -moz-transform;
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

.sidebarBtn:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black;">
  <button class="sidebarBtn">
   <span></span>
          </button>
</body>
```

Lo que si quiero que me digan donde esta la falla y como puedo resolverlo, ya que quiero quitar el rellenado y solo me quede la vizualizacion del menu sandwich. Le espero sus pronta respuestas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Mueve las líneas que están dentro de `.sidebarBtn:hover` a la clase `.sidebarBtn`.

```css
.sidebarBtn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 101;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 16px;
  /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
  width: 27px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  height: 26px;
  /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
  top: 25px;
  outline: 10px solid transparent;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.sidebarBtn span {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -1px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0 0.3s;
  transition: background 0 0.3s;
}

.sidebarBtn span:before,
.sidebarBtn span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  -moz-transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  -o-transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  transition: bottom 0.30s linear, top 0.30s linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
}

.sidebarBtn span:before {
  top: -8px;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: top, -moz-transform;
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.sidebarBtn span:after {
  bottom: -8px;
  -webkit-transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: bottom, -moz-transform;
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black;">
  <button class="sidebarBtn">
   <span></span>
          </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias ante todo

Comment: Si la solución te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para ayudar a otros programadores con tu mismo problema. Saludos.